# raising exceptions without printing

Tags: exception, python-3.x

Is there any way to raise manually created exceptions without printing or returning anything? Would pass be sufficient or is there another way?

```
try:
    a = b
    raise user_error:
except user_error:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

All exceptions are derived from `Exceptions()` so you may create your own exception class and then raise it where ever you want. If your exception isn't caught in a try-except block it will be printed. Here's how to create your own exception, raise it and catch it:

```
    class MyException(Exception):
        def __str__(self):
            print("Hello!")

    try:
        raise MyException
    except MyException:
        print("Found my own exception! :)")
```